# jQuery + PHP Issues / / Include file & AJAX not working in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been making a little ad wall plugin for WordPress that has a single settings page that allows the user to edit and save the CSS and HTML files that my plugin uses.

All it does is include a CSS and JS file on the page. This is my first time with WordPress/PHP, so it took a lot of effort to get all of my directory calling correct.

This last thing is in the way though - the JavaScript file needs to load an HTML file's contents into a div on the page, but AJAX was simply not working (directory error in console).

Here's the JS now after I tried to circumvent AJAX (don't laugh):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

      adsense = 'adsbygoogle';
  if(jQuery("." + adsense).length == 0) {
  } else {

  jQuery('body').append('<section id="asub00LOAD"></section>');
  jQuery('#asub00LOAD').html('<?php $URL = file_get_contents(plugins_url("html/adunblock.html",__FILE__ )); include_once("$URL"); ?>');

  setTimeout(function(){
    var ad = jQuery('.adsbygoogle')[0];
    var ck = window.getComputedStyle(ad,null);
    console.log(ck.display);
    if(ck.display=='none'){
      jQuery('body > div').addClass('blur');
      jQuery('.asub00').fadeIn(500);
      jQuery('.asub00_msgWin').fadeIn(1000);
    }  
    else{ }
  },1200);

  }

});
```

This being the main issue:

```
  jQuery('body').append('<section id="asub00LOAD"></section>');
  jQuery('#asub00LOAD').html('<?php $URL = file_get_contents(plugins_url("html/adunblock.html",__FILE__ )); include_once("$URL"); ?>');
```

The issue with using PHP is that I can't see it in the console, but I'm sure the issue is with the directory again. I just don't know if I should go back to trying to get the AJAX to work again now (I tried making a PHP variable in the JS file that gets the file URL and puts it in a JS var, then calling that with AJAX...didn't work out, but I still feel like I was onto something there).

Anyway, I'm frustrated and I hope someone here with experience in making plugins with WordPress might be able to see the issue fairly easily - any help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any ajax in there.

Comment: I mentioned that this is the solution I came up with to get around using AJAX since it wasn't working.

Comment: Well, did you look at the **actual** JS that's generated? Chances are you're havign a `'` inside that file that leads to syntax errors in your `.html()` call. Since it looks like you want to show static content (the contents of that HTML) file: Why not just put that `div` directly in your file and just toggle the visibility using JS / jQuery?

Comment: I want the html file separate because the entire contents is editable via the settings page. The quotation marks are in proper hierarchy if that's what you mean (alternating ' with ").

Comment: If that file is indeed included and contains even just a single `'` you're having a syntax error. Consider your file having something like `<a href='#'>Hello World</a>`. Your resulting call would be: `jQuery('#asub00LOAD').html('<a href='#'>Hello World</a>');` - see what I mean?

Comment: Also, what does the file even contain? You're reading `html/adunblock.html` and then include those contents, so presumably adunblock.html contains a filename? Why is it called .html in that case?

Comment: I don't know what you mean "contains a filename" the html file contains some divs and text, HTML elements. The HTML itself isn't even being loaded, I know this for a fact already because there are no fragments of it loading onto the page as you're suggesting might be the issue.

Comment: If the html file contains div's and text, what do you expect `include_once` to do? It's basically: `include_once("<div>...<p>....</p>...</div>");`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something about this - don't worry about it, I'll work it out. Thanks anyway.